# Firestore set() method does not insert document into collection unless get() method of ApiFuture<WriteResult> is called

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, insert

I am implementing code to insert documents into firestore with its Java API.

This does not work

```java
/**
   * Add a document to firestore database with a custom document id
   * @param collectionName the name of the collection
   * @param documentId unique document id
   * @param dataMap
   */
  public void addDocumentWithCustomDocumentId(String collectionName, String documentId, Map<String, Object> dataMap) {

  db.collection(collectionName).document(documentId).set(dataMap);
  //cannot see document inserted on Firestore console on GCP

}
```

This works though

```java
/**
   * Add a document to firestore database with a custom document id
   * @param collectionName the name of the collection
   * @param documentId unique document id
   * @param dataMap
   */
  public void addDocumentWithCustomDocumentId(String collectionName, String documentId, Map<String, Object> dataMap) {
   ApiFuture<WriteResult> result = 
          db.collection(collectionName).document(documentId).set(dataMap);
   result.get().getUpdateTime();
   //can see document inserted on Firestore console on GCP

}
```

What is the difference? Why is it necessary to call `result.get().getUpdateTime();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .get() on the call to actually run it. You could simply replace your code with

```
db.collection(collectionName).document(documentId).set(dataMap).get()
```

You can find some examples on this repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples

Comment: I checked a lot, but cannot understand what difference it makes. When I just call `db.collection(collectionName).document(documentId).set(dataMap);` the code runs successfully but no record seen on Firestore console.

Comment: Can you please show the function where the line is executed?

Comment: I have updated my question to show the entire function

Comment: Why is `.get()` needed though?

Comment: Because it allows you to "prepare" several queries and to run them in batch when you call .get()

Comment: Still not convinced. The documentation as well as the examples don't mention anywhere that it's mandatory to call `.get()` to actually perform the insertion of the document. That's quite weird. If that's the case then what is the use of the `.set()` function?

Comment: I guess it's because the documentation is generalist and in js for instance you don't have to use .get() but it's how it is implemented in the java SDK

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer though. Accepted :)