# Google Cloud Function is terminated before update to Firestore is finished

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Background Function that pulls some data from an external source. Then this data is supposed to be stored in a Firestore document. But it's never stored. The document is unchanged. Here's my code:

```java
public class MyFunction implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {

   @Override
   public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
      // pulling data from external source
      MyClass myObject = getData();
      // db is the Firestore object and was initialized earlier
      CollectionReference colRef = db.collection(MY_COL);
      DocumentReference docRef = colRef.document(MY_DOC);
      ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = docRef.set(myObject);
      ApiFutures.addCallback(future,
         new ApiFutureCallback<WriteResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
               logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                  "Failed to Update Object to Firestore", throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(WriteResult writeResult) {
               logger.info("Update Object Document ... DONE");
            }
         }, Runnable::run);
   }
}
```

The logging from `onFailure` and `onSuccess` never appear in the logs in the Firebase dashboard. It feels like the function is terminated before the write process is finished. The logs contain no errors and the data from the external source is pulled successfully.

How can I assure that the function does **not** terminate before the write process is finished?

Comment: If none of the those methods is called, then are you sure you have an internet connection?

Comment: Very sure. The data comes from an external source via HTTP calls. The function also runs in the Google Cloud.

Comment: You might have to call get() on the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968336/firestore-set-method-does-not-insert-document-into-collection-unless-get-met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` has to be called.

```java
public class MyFunction implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {

   @Override
   public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
      // pulling data from external source
      MyClass myObject = getData();
      // db is the Firestore object and was initialized earlier
      CollectionReference colRef = db.collection(MY_COL);
      DocumentReference docRef = colRef.document(MY_DOC);
      ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = docRef.set(myObject);
      future.get();
   }
}
```

IMHO this is a misleading name for this function because it suggests that the result of the future is returned but only after the future is finished. I would have expected something like `waitAndGet()` or `waitForFinish()`.